# Parsing a text file using java bufferedReader and Scanner

Tags: java, file, parsing, bufferedreader

I have the following config file that I am trying to use to set global variables in my program

```
OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = filename2.txt
MAX_CRAWL_DEPTH = 2
NUMBER OF CRAWLERS = 10
SEED_URL = https://www.lehigh.edu/home
DOMAIN = lehigh.edu
DELAY = 10
```

To parse this text file I am using this

```
String line = "";
            BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader((CONFIG_FILE_PATH)));
            Scanner charlie = new Scanner(line);

            String varName;
            while ((line = buffRead.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                charlie.useDelimiter(" = ");
                varName = charlie.next();
                System.out.println(varName);



                if (varName == "OUTPUT_FILE_PATH")
                    OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = charlie.next();
                else if (varName == "MAX_CRAWL_DEPTH")
                    MAX_CRAWL_DEPTH = charlie.nextInt();
                else if (varName == "NUMBER_OF_CRAWLERS")
                    NUMBER_OF_CRAWLERS = charlie.nextInt();
                else if (varName == "SEED_URL")
                    SEED_URL = charlie.next();
                else if (varName == "DOMAIN")
                    DOMAIN = charlie.next();
                else if (varName == "DELAY")
                    delay = charlie.nextInt();
            }
```

I get this output when running the code

```
OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = filename2.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
        at Globals.setGlobals(Globals.java:44)
```

Line 44 is where I set varName = charlie.next();
Any reason why this would be wrong? Any other tips on how to go about parsing this file? I feel like my if statements is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing the NoSuchElementException because the String you are providing in the instance of the scanner on this line:

```
Scanner charlie = new Scanner(line);
```

Is actually just:

```
Scanner charlie = new Scanner("");
```

Since you never modified `line` after you set it to `""`.

You should be doing the following:

```
Scanner charlie = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Also, a Scanner instance doesn't accept a String.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to define the scanner inside the while loop after line got updated each time, thanks everyone